# I found Error in query when i join with another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, model-view-controller

When i join one table to another then i got this error. i put as keyword but its not working it give me error like field not found how can i solve this error

Code:

```
Product::leftjoin('reviews','products.id','=','reviews.productID')
                           ->select(array('products.*',
                                    DB::raw('AVG(rating) as ratings_average')
                                ))
                        ->where(function($query) use ($categoriesID,$brands,$priceArray,$ratingArray)
                            {
                                $query->whereIn('categoryID',$categoriesID);
                                if(count($brands) > 0)
                                {
                                    $query->whereIn('brandID',$brands);
                                }
                                $query->whereBetween('productSellingPrice',$priceArray);
                                if(count($ratingArray) > 0)
                                {
                                    $query->whereBetween('ratings_average',$ratingArray);
                                }
                            })
                        ->groupBy('products.id')
                        ->get();
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ratings_average' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `products`.*, AVG(rating) as ratings_average from `products` left join `reviews` on `products`.`id` = `reviews`.`productID` where (`categoryID` in (9, 11, 31) and `productSellingPrice` between 50 and 5000 and `ratings_average` between 1 and 2) group by `products`.`id`)
```

Comment: Does your table have a column called `ratings_average`?

Comment: i use   DB::raw('AVG(rating) as ratings_average' @TZHX

Comment: sorry i cant understand you @TZHX

Comment: You don't have a column with that name, so you can't include it in a condition. That's basic MySQL.

Comment: just check my query i use as keyword for average @TZHX

Comment: Do you have `average` column in the table?

Comment: No i dont have i join product table with review table then find average @BasheerAhmed

Comment: So basically you want to join two tables and based on that you want the average? So the average of which column to get?

Comment: My query is like this                                                                           select `products`.*, AVG(rating) as productRating from `products` left join `reviews` on `products`.`id` = `reviews`.`productID` where (`categoryID` in (9, 11, 31) and `productSellingPrice` between 50 and 5000 and productRating between 0 and 1) group by `products`.`id`  @BasheerAhmed

Comment: On which column you want to get the  `AVG`? E.x `price` etc

Comment: rating column @BasheerAhmed

Comment: I think this also problem in the query `where ( categoryID in` where `(` is coming between a column and where condition

Comment: yaar its not a problem when i put quote marks on productRating field and run query in phpmyadmin  then its work otherwise in code not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101883/discussion-between-ekta-singh-and-basheer-ahmed).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rating array you can find out `$minRating` and `maxRating`. By these two value you can run you query like this:

```
$query->whereBetween('rating',[$minRating,$maxRtaing]);
```

Comment: use this `$query->whereBetween('AVG(\`rating\`)',$ratingArray);` Not sure if you need the backticks on the AVG value but everything else is backticked on your question. @ektasingh

Comment: @ektasingh I edited my answer. Let see it helps or not.

Comment: actually its not find the rating field  it gives me error on rating field

Comment: Because the `ratings_average` field is not exist in your table. You have to run all queries using `rating`. This `AVG(rating) as ratings_average` will only treat the field name as `rating_average` while returning the result of query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a SQL problem, and it has to do with scoping.  I'm not well versed in laravel's API, but the SQL generated (based on your helpful error message) is:

```
select `products`.*, AVG(rating) as ratings_average 
    from `products` left join `reviews` on `products`.`id` = `reviews`.`productID`
    where (`categoryID` in (9, 11, 31) and `productSellingPrice` between 50 and 5000
        and `ratings_average` between 1 and 2) group by `products`.`id`)
```

The problem is that the `ratings_average` calculated column belongs to the `GROUP BY` scope.  The only way to reference that column is in a `HAVING` statement.  Your SQL statement would look like this:

```
select `products`.*, AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) as ratings_average
    where `products`.`id` = `reviews`.`productId`
    group by `products`.`id`
    having (`categoryID` in (9, 11, 31) and `productSellingPrice` between 50 and 5000
        and `ratings_average` between 1 and 2)
```

Technically speaking, the first two clauses in the having statement above could be in your `WHERE` clause, but the `ratings_average` named column can only be referenced in the `HAVING` clause.  Both WHERE and HAVING restrict your results, but HAVING is evaluated after the grouping took place.

Comment: How can i solve my problem if i use having  then i found error in grammer.php that strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: I can't answer the API specific question, just the SQL that needs to be generated.  As I mentioned in my answer, I'm not well versed in laravel's API.